# ServiceStack IOC: How to register templated class

Tags: servicestack

I have the following repository classes for Redis databases:

```
public class RedisRepositoryBase<TRedisEntity> : IRedisRepository<TRedisEntity> where TRedisEntity : class, IRedisEntity
public class MyClassARepository : RedisRepositoryBase<MyClassA>
public class MyClassBRepository : RedisRepositoryBase<MyClassB>
public class MyClassCRepository : RedisRepositoryBase<MyClassC>
```

`TRedisEntity` is the base class of my POCOs where some common props like `Id`, `CreationDate` and others are defined. The constructor of the derived repo classes is defined as such:

```
public MyClassARepository(IRedisClientsManager redisManager) : base(redisManager)
{
}
```

Now I try to register those repositories in my AppHost class:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(connStr)); // the connection pool
    // Now I do not understand how to register the repositories
    container.Register<IRedisRepository<IRedisEntity>>(c => new MyClassARepository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()); //This is wrong, get conversion error!
    // ... other configuration stuff
}
```

Reading the ServiceStack IOC docs, I see there are many ways to register my repos but I cannot get it going....

I guess I have to register all my derived classes or is this a wrong assumption?
What is the correct syntax to register my repo classes with Func?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyClassARepository` only implements `IRedisRepository<MyClassA>` so you can only do:

```
container.Register<IRedisRepository<MyClassA>>(c => 
    new MyClassARepository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>());
```